Jetpack Compose layout jumps when IME opens
So I have this BottomSheetScaffold layout with a CenterAlignedTopAppBar and a bottom sheet with some text fields.
Below are modifier that I presume might be useful:
// root composable, NavHost modifier
Modifier.fillMaxSize().imePadding()

// screen-level composable, BottomSheetScaffold
Modifier.fillMaxSize()

// modifier for a content column inside the BottomSheetScaffold
Modifier.padding(paddingValues).fillMaxSize()

So when I click on a text field inside the bottom sheet, the whole layout does an awful shift (I guess it tries to do some kind of animation) and then gets resized to appropriate dimensions.
Here's a video demonstration
Is there a way this can be avoided?
I've tried setting android:windowSoftInputMode to all different kinds of values, like adjustPan, adjustResize, adjustNothing, but this didn't work.
Also tried setting android:animateLayoutChanges to false, but this didn't work either.
I did also try to apply imePadding modifier to different parts of the layout, but unless it's on NavHost, the paddings are weird and inappropriate, so I assume that NavHost (or any other top-level composable in your activity) is indeed the right place to put this modifier.
The most basic code sample that resembles my problem as closely as possible:
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            var input by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            ImeLayoutJumpShiftTheme {
                Box(modifier = Modifier.imePadding()) {
                    BottomSheetScaffold(
                        topBar = { TopAppBar(title = { Text("Example") }) },
                        sheetPeekHeight = 125.dp,
                        sheetContent = {
                            Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
                                TextField(value = input, onValueChange = { input = it })
                            }
                        }
                    ) { paddingValues ->
                        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)) {
                            items(12) {
                                ListItem(
                                    headlineContent = { Text("Item $it") },
                                    supportingContent = {
                                        Text("This is item #$it. It increases the amount of space this list item takes up to recreate the usage of list items in a real project.")
                                    }
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


When android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified" or by default is set keyboard animation is not synchronized with the maximum space it will reach at the end. Views or Composable go faster than keyboard.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/sw-keyboard
In windowSoftInputMode is adjustNothing or adjustPan is set it pushes everything up to display TextField if it's below max height of keyboard and has this terrible animation, however when you use android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" animation is smoother but it doesn't push TextField up. This is easy to overcome either with
Modifier.imePadding() or setting an offset based on current height of sw keyboard.
The issue with Modifier.imePadding is how it works. The misconception people have, including me before testing, with it is thinking it pushes your Composable above keyboard but it doesn't.
It adds padding to bottom of the Composable it's assigned to. And works best like in Composable if there is a space to shrink, for instance a Spacer(weight(1f)), so it can add padding to Composable at the bottom while shrinking space above it. In view if you check how adjustResize works with Views they use it inside a ConstraintsLayout EditText anchored to bottom.
However, if there are any Composables above it, it just adds padding bottom  or might not do anything at all. You can consider this as adding padding to last item, or parent's bottom if it's assigned to parent.
With android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .systemBarsPadding()
        .imePadding()
) {
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    TopAppBar(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        title = {
            Text("TopAppbar")
        }
    )

    // Comment repeat block to see difference
    repeat(10) {
        Text(
            text = "Text: $it",
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
        )
    }

   Column {
       Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
       TextField(text, onValueChange = { text = it })
       Text("Bottom Text")
   }
}


If you comment repeat block

This Modifier actually should have been Modifier.offset to work properly with every layout since setting offset does not push siblings. And it's easy to make one but you need to set WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false) to be able to get current keyboard height.
val density = LocalDensity.current
val bottom: Int = WindowInsets.ime.getBottom(density)
val bottomDp: Dp = with(density) { bottom.toDp() }

Adding offset or padding below Composable works when you don't use BottomSheets, because it has peekHeight. In OP's case more precise solution requires reproducible example.

Sorry, I didn't quite get the idea... I'll sketch up a quick demo for you by the end of the day and maybe you can take a look at it and suggest a fix for the problem I'm having. Thanks for taking your time to respond

What i mean is if you use adjustResize animation is smoother. But then it doesn't move TextField up. And you have to assign imePadding but it doesn't work in every case. So you need to get current keyboard height use it offset or in another way to change position of TextField

imePadding is just a padding. It works well if you have space above that can shrink which is possible with aligning something to bottom or when you use Spacer with weight to fill space between. Since it's a padding it changes how other siblings are measured because it uses space in parent. However,  you can set offset which doesn't effect other Composables or add size, etc, using current keyboard size.

Also in the link i shared, you can check out the video. Views or Composable are not synchronised with keyboard. And it requires you to use ViewCompat.setWindowInsetsAnimationCallback with the View you need to synch with. But this doesn't work with Composables, so you need to do this synch with current keyboard height unfortunately.

I've added a code sample at the end of my question so feel free to check it out and give any suggestions as to what I can do
